# Builderror after upgrading to xcode4.3.2 from xcode3.2

Tags: macos, xcode4.3

We have upgraded our xcode to 4.3 recently.
I am into testing, I need to duplicate target file and integrate FoneMonkey files and execute the target.
I did below changes to orginal target to get it executed successfully:

```
updated framework serch paths

"$(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR)"
"$(SRCROOT)/../../Developer/Library/Frameworks"
"$(SRCROOT)"

updated Library search paths

"$(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR)"
"$(SRCROOT)/../../Developer/Library/Frameworks"
"$(SRCROOT)"
"/users/ezprintsqa/FoneMonkey/lib"

executed below command 
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Now build gets executed successfully.
But the duplicate target with Fonemonkey files added gives below errors:

```
Ld "/Users/ezprintsqa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SnapCards-dtjqrhfvqueyhrbbgjgydberyqdm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SnapCards copy.app/SnapCards copy" normal i386
    cd /Users/ezprintsqa/Documents/snapcards
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/ezprintsqa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SnapCards-dtjqrhfvqueyhrbbgjgydberyqdm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/CPlusTest.framework -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/DTPerformanceSession.framework -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/InterfaceBuilderKit.framework -L/
.
.

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/ezprintsqa/Documents/snapcards/../../Developer/Library/Frameworks'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/ezprintsqa/Documents/snapcards/../../Developer/Library/Frameworks'
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability stopNotifier] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability isReachable] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability isConnectionRequired] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability isConnectionOnDemand] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability isInterventionRequired] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability isReachableViaWWAN] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability isReachableViaWiFi] in Reachability.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestSuite", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFoneMonkeyOCUnit.5.5b.a(FoneMonkey+OCUnit.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestObserver", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFoneMonkeyOCUnit.5.5b.a(FoneMonkey+OCUnit.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestLog", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFoneMonkeyOCUnit.5.5b.a(FoneMonkey+OCUnit.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can some one please help me with below issues:

1. The folder `/Users/ezprintsqa/Library/Developer/` is not available now after upgrading to 4.3, but here this path is being configured (how can i change this)?
2. The _objc_class issues.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

By removing `SenTesting.framework` from Xcode the issue was solved.